# Adding symbols for vector layer

Tags: symbology, import, library

I'm trying to figure out how to add some public safety symbols to QGIS (3.34.2) like a simple and clean symbol for a firehouse location... having trouble.

Alternatively is there an existing library of symbols that can be turned on or imported?